# Field properties in QGIS are lost when polygon layer shape file is reloaded

Tags: qgis

I have been creating Shapefile polygon layers.  The Attributes Form is used to create a Value Map in the 'Widget Type' section and everything works fine.  The Value Map option creates a combo box pull down of options.  The layer is saved off as a shapefile, but when it's reloaded, the 'Value Map' settings are lost along with any default settings for other fields.  Is there a way to preserve these settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the style of your shapefile separately in a .qml file. Your forms, symbology and labels will be saved in it. 
You can then import that style on your shapefile in any qgis project. If you give your style the same name as your shapefile parts, your layer should automatically import the style along with the geometry and data table.